# Bedeutung von "austragen"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, verb, meaning-in-context

Als ich auf das Wort „austragen“ gestoßen bin, habe ich herausgefunden, dass ich die Bedeutung nicht ganz verstehe, in der es in Ausdrücken wie "einen Streit, Konflikt, Kampf austragen" verwendet wird. [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/austragen) sagt, dass es "klärend abschließen, entscheiden, ausfechten" bedeutet, zeigt also den Abschluss der Aktion an, fast genauso ist es mit [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/austragen). Trotzdem geht aus den Beispielen, die unter anderem DWDS angibt, dass "austragen" darin eher "durchführen" bedeutet, z.B. in "Der Streik wird auf dem Rücken der Kinder und Eltern ausgetragen" oder "Hier wird der härteste Kampf um Wohnraum und Mieten ausgetragen". Mir scheint, diese Sätze bedeuten nicht, dass die Aktion schon komplett ist — im Gegenteil, sie geht noch weiter, ist noch nicht klärend abgeschlossen. Was denken Sie darüber?

Comment: Inwiefern wird dein Verständnis nicht von der Bedeutung "ausfechten" im Duden abgedeckt?

Comment: @JonathanScholbach "Ausfechten" setzt auch eine abgeschlossene Aktion voraus, oder?

Comment: Für mich nicht: _Sie fechten einen Kampf aus_ beschreibt in meinen Augen einen gegenwärtig ablaufenden Vorgang. Aber ich kann mir täuschen.

Comment: @JonathanScholbach Da Sie Muttersprachler sind, würde ich lieber Ihnen glauben. Danke!

Comment: Einen Streit kann man austragen (Ggw.), ausgetragen haben (Verg.) und austragen wollen/werden (Zukunft). Der Abschluss gehört zur Motivation der Handlung, aber ungeachtet dessen kann der Abschluss in der Vergangenheit, Ggw. oder Zukunft liegen - wie bei allen anderen Verben, soweit mir bekannt. Keines fixiert die Zeit im Wortstamm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"austragen" hat verschiedene Bedeutungen, die - wie bei allen solchen Worten - aus dem Kontext hervorgehen:

**[ein Kind]** austragen: bedeutet, die Schwangerschaft endend mit einer regulären Geburt fortsetzen (im Gegensatz zu: eine Schwangerschaftsunterbrechung haben, das Kind verlieren, etc.). Der Begriff wird nicht nur bei menschlichen sondern auch tierischen Schwangerschaften verwendet. "Die Kuh hat schon mehrmals Kälber ausgetragen."

**[eine Auseinandersetzung]** austragen: bedeutet, die Auseinandersetzung (Kampf, Wettkampf, Streit, Wortgefecht, ...) durchzuführen. Wenn jemand das vermeiden will, so *weicht* er der jeweiligen Auseinandersetzung *aus*, *vermeidet* sie, usw.. Das Wort selbst ist neutral den Mitteln gegenüber: man kann etwas *vor Gericht austragen* (einen Prozeß führen), man kann es auch *mit den Fäusten austragen* (sich prügeln), *mit Waffen austragen* (Krieg führen), und ähnliches.

**[Post]** austragen: die Post(-sendungen) (oder Zeitungen, Werbesendungen, ...) an die jeweiligen Adressaten verteilen. Die typische Tätigkeit eines Briefträgers, Zeitungsjungen und dgl..

**[aus einer Liste]** austragen: bedeutet das Gegenteil von "eintragen": einen Eintrag in einer Liste (oder ähnlichen Dingen) entfernen. Wer zu einer Veranstaltung tatsächlich kommt, der wird in die Liste der Anwesenden *eingetragen* und aus der Liste der Nichtgekommenen *ausgetragen*.

Das Wort sagt auch nichts über den Status der jeweiligen Aktivität aus: eine (Schach-, Fußball-, ...) Partie kann *ausgetragen worden sein*, dann ist diese Austragung vorüber, vorgestern aber wurde gestreikt, da *wird der eben stattfindende Arbeitskampf mit dem Mittel des Streiks ausgetragen*, die Austragung ist gerade in vollem Gange. Man kann das vielleicht auch *vor Gericht austragen*, da hat die gerichtliche Auseinandersetzung noch gar nicht begonnen, sondern wird nur als Möglichkeit in den Raum gestellt.

Comment: Alles klar, vielen Dank!